# Running same testng test on different threads

Tags: multithreading, testng, sequential

I want to run a testng test on different threads such that all the methods in that test run sequentially on the same thread.
How can I implement this by making changes in xml file or in the class through which I am executing testng test?

This is my testng test class:

```
 import java.util.*;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@Test(singleThreaded=true)
public class Calculator2  {
 Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
 Date starttime;
 Date endtime;
 long stime;
 long etime;

   public void add() {

     starttime=calendar.getTime();
     stime=System.nanoTime();

     System.out.println
     (new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName().toUpperCase());     // output :doit
     System.out.println("start time: "+starttime);
     Random r=new Random();
     double inputA=r.nextDouble();
     double   inputB=r.nextDouble();
     double answer = inputA+inputB;
     System.out.println(answer+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
     endtime=calendar.getTime();
     etime=System.nanoTime();
     System.out.println("end time: "+endtime);
     long duration=etime-stime;
    // System.out.println("start time add:"+starttime+"  "+"end time:"+endtime+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
     System.out.println("duration:"+duration/100000.000);  


}

  public void  subtract() {
    starttime=calendar.getTime(); 
    stime=System.nanoTime();
     System.out.println
     (new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName().toUpperCase()); // output :doit
     System.out.println("start time: "+starttime);

     Random r=new Random();
     double inputA=r.nextDouble();
     double   inputB=r.nextDouble();
     double answer = inputA-inputB;
     System.out.println(answer+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId()); 
     endtime=calendar.getTime();
     System.out.println("end time: "+endtime);
     etime=System.nanoTime();
     long duration=etime-stime;

     System.out.println("duration:"+duration/1000000.000); 

  }

    public  void multiply() {
    starttime=calendar.getTime();
     stime=System.nanoTime();
     System.out.println
     (new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName().toUpperCase()); // output :doit
     System.out.println("start time: "+starttime);
     Random r=new Random();
     double inputA=r.nextDouble();
     double   inputB=r.nextDouble();
     double answer = inputA*inputB;
     System.out.println(answer+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
     endtime=calendar.getTime();
     etime=System.nanoTime();
     System.out.println("end time: "+endtime);
     long duration=etime-stime;

     System.out.println("duration:"+duration/1000000.000);
}

       public void divide() {
    starttime=calendar.getTime();
     stime=System.nanoTime();
     System.out.println
     (new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName().toUpperCase()); // output :doit
     System.out.println("start time: "+starttime);
     Random r=new Random();
     double inputA=r.nextDouble();
     double   inputB=r.nextDouble();
     double answer = inputA/inputB;
     System.out.println(answer+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());;     
     endtime=calendar.getTime();
     etime=System.nanoTime();
     System.out.println("end time: "+endtime);
     long duration=etime-stime;
   //  System.out.println("start time div:"+starttime+"  "+"end time:"+endtime);
     System.out.println("duration:"+duration/1000000.000);

}

  public void power() throws InterruptedException{
starttime=calendar.getTime();
 stime=System.nanoTime();
 System.out.println
 (new Exception().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName().toUpperCase()); // output :doit
 System.out.println("start time: "+starttime);
     Random r=new Random();
     double inputA=r.nextDouble();
     double   inputB=r.nextDouble();
     double answer =inputA;

    for (int x=2; x<=inputB; x++){
        answer *= inputA;
    }

    System.out.println(answer+" "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    endtime=calendar.getTime();
    etime=System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("end time: "+endtime);
    long duration=etime-stime;
  //  System.out.println("start time pow:"+starttime+"  "+"end time:"+endtime);
    System.out.println("duration"+duration/1000000.000); 

}

 }
```

This is the class from where I am running the test:

```
  package TestNg.src;

import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;
 import java.util.Properties;
 import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
 import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
  import org.testng.TestNG;
 import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

 public class Test1 {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    File configFile = new File("name.properties");
    Properties prope = new Properties();
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(configFile);
    prope.load(reader);
    String s = prope.getProperty("class-name");

    final Class<?> cl = Class.forName(s);

    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { cl });

    Transformer myTransformer = new Transformer();

    testng.setThreadCount(20);
    testng.setParallel("tests");
    //testng.setDataProviderThreadCount(20);
    testng.setAnnotationTransformer(myTransformer);
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();

   }
 }

class Transformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
  public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass,
        Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {

    annotation.setInvocationCount(5);

}
}
```